# No serializer found for class rx.Observable using Jersey RxJava client

Tags: java, jersey, jackson, rx-java, jersey-client

I'm creating an API resource that uses the Jersey RxJava client to aggregate other resources into a single response.  However, I'm getting an error returned which is a bit puzzling.  The object being returned is a JSONArray but I'm getting this:

```
No serializer found for class rx.Observable and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: org.json.simple.JSONArray[0])
```

and method:

```
@Override
public void getUsersDashboard(String token, String userId, @Suspended final AsyncResponse async) {
    List<JSONObject> list = //query persistence layer

    final Queue<String> errors = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

    final List<Observable> observables = list.stream()
            .map(jsonObject -> (String) jsonObject.get("href"))
            .map(link -> dashboard(token, link, errors))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    Observable.just(new JSONArray())
            .zipWith(observables, (jsonArray, resultFromObservable) -> {
                jsonArray.add(resultFromObservable);
                return jsonArray;
            })
            .subscribe(async::resume, async::resume);
}
```

Any ideas what would be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your `observables` list is of type `List<Observable>`. From this I assume that the `dashboard` method returns an `Observable<?>`; further assuming that it returns a `Observable<T extends JSONNode>`, I would rewrite your method as follows:

```
@Override
public void getUsersDashboard(String token, String userId, @Suspended final AsyncResponse async) {
    List<JSONObject> list = //query persistence layer

    final Queue<String> errors = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

    Observable
    .fromIterable(list)
    .map(jsonObject -> (String) jsonObject.get("href"))
    .flatMap(link -> dashboard(token, link, errors))
    .collect(JSONArray::new, JSONArray::add)
    .subscribe(async::resume, async::resume);
}
```

The zip method would also kinda work if you used the following line:

```
.zipWith(Observable.merge(observables), (jsonArray, resultFromObservable) -> {
```

However, `zip()` takes one element out of each observable, meaning that you would end up with an array of size one.

Comment: I thought I had solved it by removing the Observables collection, but was only getting one item emitted due to using 'just' (I think). Your suggested refactor is spot on, thanks!  (Although I used .from(list) since Jersey RxJava client doesn't use RxJava 2.x it appears)